# reading a TXT file into a CSV file for writing without importing the CSV module

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I wrote this program to read a text file and put the contents line by line into another cvs file for writing. However, I would like to open the first txt file for reading, open another txt file for writing, and  copy the contents of txt file 1 into txt file 2 without commas. For example, a line "1, 2, hello" should read "1 2 hello". I currently have it opening a csv file for writing, but I would like it to open a txt file for writing.

```
import csv

with open('texfile.txt', 'r') as in_file:
    stripped = (line.strip() for line in in_file)
    lines = (line.split(",") for line in stripped if line)
    with open('csvfile.csv', 'w') as out_file:
        writer = csv.writer(out_file)
        writer.writerows(lines)
```

Comment: You can look at the source for the csv module and see what it does.

Comment: Why don't you want to import the `csv` module? You can't use a `csv.writer` without importing the module

Comment: "I would like to do this without importing the CSV function in my program" - That is a bad idea.

Comment: @KenWhite fixed question. I meant I'm currently opening it into a CSV file for writing but would like to do the same thing except open it in a txt file.

Comment: Do you mean you want the CSV file to open in a text editor?

Comment: Or do you want to simply remove all commas from an ordinary text file? Is it supposed to be a CSV at all?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I want to open the first txt file for reading, and read in each line to another txt file for writing without commas. For example, a line "1, 2, hello" should read "1 2 hello". I currently have it opening a csv file for writing

Comment: It sounds like your question has literally nothing to do with the CSV format and all you want to do is remove all of a certain character from a file.

Comment: JD wants to take a TXT file in which has commas, remove the commas and save the file as .csv but really with the space delimiter.

Comment: @Garren - Do they? It's totally unclear.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Fixed the question does this make more sense?

Comment: Looks like my suspicions were correct; this has nothing at all to do with CSV and all you want to do is remove all instances of a certain character from a file.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input txt file is safe to parse via the simple ".split()" function (as you've specified), writing to a basic CSV file should be straightforward:

```
with open('csvfile.csv', 'w') as out_file:
  for line in lines:
    out_file.write(" ".join(line) + "\n")
```

NOTE: Using the CSV module would still be best.

Comment: This will add extra spaces. I think OP might simply want `with open(a) as i, open(b, 'w') as o: b.write(a.read().replace(',', ''))`.